# Adobe Garamond Pro not working with XeLaTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, opentype

Adobe Garamond Pro and XeLaTeX
Guys, I am trying to use opentype fonts using XeLaTeX. Now when, I am trying to use Adobe Garamond Pro. It says

> ! Font `\zf@basefont=Garamond` at 10.0pt
>   not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or
>   installed font not found.

My operating system is Fedora 12. The /usr/share/fonts contain both folder name linux-libertine and Garamond in which it contains the .otf files. When of use Linux Libertine it is fine with Latex but Adobe Garamond Pro shows error. See the code below:

**For Linux Libertine**

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine} % could be any Unicode font
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{document}
```

**Output:**
[image]

**Now using Garamond - Code**

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont{Garamond} % could be any Unicode font
%\setmainfont{Adobe Garamond Pro} % could be any Unicode font
%\setmainfont{AGaramond Pro} % could be any Unicode font
%I have used all possible combination.
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{document}
```

**Output is a BLANK File**

```
The log says something like this:
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/fixltx2e.sty))
! Font \zf@basefont=Garamond at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or insta
lled font not found.
\zf@fontspec ...ntname \zf@suffix " at \f@size pt 
                                                  \unless \ifzf@icu \zf@set@...
l.3 \setmainfont{Garamond}
                           % could be any Unicode font
?
```

As you can see, I have tried every possible way to name the font.

So what should I do to fix this serious issues?

P.S. Both fonts are installed in my computer.
Verification:

```
ls -R /usr/share/fonts/linux-libertine/ /usr/share/fonts/linux-libertine/: LinBiolinumB.ttf  LinLibertineBI.ttf  LinLibertineC.ttf  LinLibertine.ttf LinBiolinum.ttf   LinLibertineB.ttf   LinLibertineI.ttf

ls -R /usr/share/fonts/Garamond/
/usr/share/fonts/Garamond/:
AGaramondPro-BoldItalic.otf  AGaramondPro-Regular.otf
AGaramondPro-Bold.otf        AGaramondPro-SemiboldItalic.otf
AGaramondPro-Italic.otf      AGaramondPro-Semibold.otf
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you get those fonts? I have Fedora 18 and the files aren't there, there isn't any package to install that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For me your sample works just fine, with the line:

`\setmainfont{Adobe Garamond Pro}`

uncommented (and the previous one commented out).

I suspect the font isn't cached. Try running `[sudo] fc-cache -fv`

Answer (score 2):

Use `fc-query <font-name>` and examine the *family* and perhaps also the *fullname* field to make certain you've tried the correct name to use.

If that doesn't work, use something like `fc-list | grep -i gara` to make sure the system knows about the font. If it doesn't, run `fc-cache -v` and try again.

If that doesn't work, then I don't have any other ideas.

Comment: [Ujjwol@lamichhane ~]$ fc-list | grep -i gara
Adobe Garamond Pro,Adobe Garamond Pro Bold:style=Bold
Adobe Garamond Pro,Adobe Garamond Pro Bold:style=Bold Italic
Adobe Garamond Pro:style=Semibold,Bold
Adobe Garamond Pro:style=Regular
Adobe Garamond Pro:style=Italic
Adobe Garamond Pro:style=Semibold Italic,Bold Italic

Comment: It worked man! with \setmainfont{Adobe Garamond Pro} after i did fc-cache -fv as frabjous said.

Comment: BTW:I didn't get the command fc-query <font-name>.

Comment: I think `fc-query` is recent addition to fontconfig and might not be available in all distros. TeXLive ships with `otfinfo` (part of LCDF tools), which provides similar functionality.

Answer (score 1):

As a note for other who might bump into this problem: try using a minimal document without additional packages if a given font doesn't seem to work. For instance the `ngerman` package can interfere with font loading and produce the messsage shown above.

Answer (score 1):

A tip for those running into this problem on OS X is the following.  It is possible that your OS X font cache is corrupted somehow.  To reset this, execute the following:

- `sudo atsutil databases -remove`
- `atsutil server -shutdown`
- `atsutil server -ping`

The first removes all user font caches, the second shuts down the font server, and the third starts it up again (may take a moment).